# Why are these operations allowed when proving linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $V, W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ and $\gamma = \{w_1, \ldots, w_m\}$ and our linear transformations are defined by $T_{ij}: V \to W$ where

$$T_{ij}(v_k) = \begin{cases}w_i & \text{if } k = j \\ 0 & \text{if } k \neq j \end{cases}$$

I tried to show that the set of functions $\{T_{ij} : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ is linear independent. My idea, which failed miserably, was to write $x \in V$ as a linear combination of vectors in $\beta$ and then work from there, but I get stuck because I end up not being able to discard the scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ that are associated with $x = c_1v_1 + \cdots c_n v_n$. I eventually gave up and the unofficial answers I have access to write their argument as follows:

if $\sum\limits_{i, j} a_{ij}T_{ij} = 0$, then we have $( \sum\limits_{i, j} a_{ij}T_{ij} ) (v_k) = \sum\limits_{i} a_{ij}T_{ik}(v_k) = \sum\limits_{i} a_{ik}w_i$ $ \implies a_{ik} = 0$

I both don't understand why we can directly use any particular chosen basis vector, $v_k$, and I don't understand why we can generalize the final implication to the entirety of $j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}T_{ij} = 0$ means that $\left(\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}T_{ij}\right)(x) = 0$ for any $x \in V$.

When applying this, you may choose any vector for $x$ you want, in particular you could choose $x = v_k$ for any $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Choosing such a $k$ and then using the the assumption $\gamma$ is a basis, we can conclude as in the given solution that $a_{ik} = 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$.  Since $k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ was arbitrary, the conclusion of $a_{ik} = 0$ applies to all $1\leq i \leq m, 1 \leq k \leq n.$

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation $S$ is $0$ if $Sx=0$ **for all $x$**. Hence $\sum a_{ij} T_{ij} $ implies $\sum a_{ij} T_{ij} v_k=0$ for each $k$. This yields $\sum a_{ik} w_k=0$ for each $k$ and linear independence of $w_k$'s now shows that $a_{ik}=0$ for all $k$ and all $i$.